# Is there way to use interpolation inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

```
<div *ngFor="let t of {{randomName}}"></div>
```

I want to pass the array name dynamically, i tried above code but i got error.

Thanks for answers but i have to update the question with my scenario

```
<div formArrayName="{{obj.key}}">
 <div *ngFor="let t of formGrp.controls.{{obj.key}}.controls"></div>
</div>
```

I am creating form array dynamically and it can have any name depending on schema. I   am able to bind that dynamic name to formArrayName as it supports interpolation but i need same behaviour on loop also

Comment: what is the error? you need not add the `interpolation` it will work without that itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be easy by using square brackets notation:

```
<div *ngFor="let t of formGrp.controls[obj.key].controls"></div>
                                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ewxfk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 2):

`<div *ngFor="let t of getTheData()"></div>`

`getTheData` is a method in your component that returns the data

Check the example here https://plnkr.co/edit/Ma66tJhpldYY4GuuM3uU?p=preview in the `.component.ts`

Comment: If you're doing this, it would be better to use a get accessor rather than a function. html: `<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes"></div>` ts: `get heroes() { return this._heroes; }` better readability

Answer (score 2):

```
<div *ngFor="let t of dynamicArr"></div>
```

What you can do is set the Array dynamically in your component. Rather than using string interpolation.

```
export class SomeClass {
   dynamicArr:[];  
   updateArr(){
     // some logic
   return this.dynamicArr = dynamic Array
   }
}
```